# Не получается исправить вывод данных даты и времени

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

У меня в datagridview, в столбике времени почему-то, помимо времени, выводится дата 30.12.1899:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPB12.png]

Код:

```
private void Frm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "бДDataSet.Рейсы". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
    this.рейсыTableAdapter.Fill(this.бДDataSet.Рейсы);

    MyConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
    comm.Connection = MyConn;
    comm.CommandText = ("SELECT Класс, ГородаВылета, ГородаПрилета, ДатаВылета, ВремяВылета, ВремяПрилёта, Тарифы FROM Рейсы WHERE Класс = @clas AND ГородаВылета = @с1 AND ГородаПрилета = @с2");
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clas", Point.TextClass);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@с1", Point.Text1);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@с2", Point.Text2);

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);


    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    adapter.SelectCommand = comm;
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    MyConn.Close();
}
```

Также при нажатии на строку данные выводились в label, но у меня даты с временем криво вводятся: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fFRF.png]

Код вывода данных в label:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE1eu.png]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0

Comment: Насколько я вижу, вы привязываете DataTable к DataGridView. Это не совсем корректно. Воспользуйтесь ответом по ссылке https://clck.ru/nJvur (раздел про привязку данных). Для корректного вывода воспользуйтесь форматирование datetime в string https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1